# Field of definition for a representation and Brauer group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, brauer-groups

I wonder if the following logic is true. And if it is true, how to prove it?

Let $G$ be a profinite group, $\rho:G\to GL_n(k)$ a continuous representation, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field with characteristic $p$. If the character of $\rho$ is defined over a finite subfield $l\subset k$, then since the Brauer group of $l$ is trivial, $\rho$ can be defined over $l$.

More generally, for any group $G$, and a representation $\rho:G\to GL_n(F)$ over some field $F$, if its character is defined over some subfield $K$ with $Br(K)$ trivial, then $\rho$ can also be defined over $K$.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: I think the character is not the right think to use here in characteristic $p$. Imagine taking a representation defined over an enormous field and taking the direct sum of $p$ copies of it. Maybe one could do better using the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @WillSawin maybe the OP meant irreducible representation.

Comment: I think either taking the characteristic polynomial or regard it as irreducible representation is OK. I just want to know the rough idea of how this is done. I saw this kind of reasoning many times but I did not know the details involved in it.